# Regex: Match NOT curved or square bracket

Tags: regex

This isn't matching. I want to match a string of characters that are not `]` or `)`.

I used this regular expression, but it isn't matching '`[^\\)\\]]+`'

I'm sure its simple, but, help please :)

Working in R:

```
gsub('[\\(\\[]{1}[^\\)\\]]+[\\)\\]]{1}','','JOSH [IS MY NAME]')
```

Does not match anything. I want it to remove the data between the square brackets.

Comment: can you show us your code..

Comment: The regular expression should do it's job, do you have an example of where it's being used?

Comment: Maybe its an R problem? I get a \ ] is not a valid escape character error

Answer (score 2):

The regex would be

```
\\[[^\\[\\]]+\\]
```

This would replace anything within brackets..replace it with `[]`

Answer (score 1):

AH. 
I had to set perl=TRUE argument and it worked. 
All better thanks guys!